# Iteration in Mutable State

Tags: iteration, mutable, ml

I would like to write a function that accepts a function which performs an operation on the elements of a list, and accepts the list as an argument as well.  I am trying to practice with anonymous functions and iterate through a list without using the built in iter in OCaml.
I also wrote a test case which should pass when this function is completed.  I am struggling to figure out how to do this, as I want to perform an operation on each element without returning anything, rather updating the list by this iterative operation.

This is how I have started and would like to maintain this format:
Any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let rec iteration (f: 'h -> unit) (l: 'h list) : unit =



let test () : bool =
let list = [1; 2; 3] in
iteration (fun r -> r * 2) list;
list = [2; 4; 6]
;; run_test "iteration" test
```

Comment: Lists are immutable. (And `(fun r -> r * 2)` doesn't have the type `int -> unit`.)